# Wordpress URL Rewrite to sync custom taxonomy and post type

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, url-routing

Here are my current URLs for my custom post type and taxonomy. I noticed the rewrite slug for the custom post type and taxonomy cannot both be "inventory" or it breaks. So i went with "inventory-category" and "inventory".

**current urls:**

category
http://localhost:3000/inventory-category/actual-category-name/

single
http://localhost:3000/inventory/product-title

**I want:**

category
http://localhost:3000/inventory/actual-category-name/

single
http://localhost:3000/inventory/actual-category-name/product-title

**So I have 2 questions**

1. How do I get the post type and taxonomy to both share the same url "inventory" instead of using "inventory-category".
2. How do I get the single to use the actual category name? So it could be:

http://localhost:3000/inventory/cars/product-title

http://localhost:3000/inventory/trucks/product-title

```
// register a new list of categories for custom post type
function so_inventory_categories() {
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'       => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_admin_column'  => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'rewrite'            => array('with_front' => false, 'slug' => 'inventory-category'),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'inventory_categories', array( 'inventory' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'so_inventory_categories' );

function so_posttype_inventory() {
    $args = array(
        'labels'              => ['name'=>'Inventory'],
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'inventory_categories' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
        'rewrite'             => array('with_front' => false,'slug' => 'inventory'),
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-plus-alt',
    );
    register_post_type( 'inventory', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'so_posttype_inventory', 0 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use rewrite rules to make that work. Something like this:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^inventory/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?taxonomy=inventory_category&inventory_category=$matches[1]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^inventory/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=inventory&inventory=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
```

I haven't tested this so it might still need some tweaking.

Comment: This works! thanks! Next question. I now have multiple urls that go to the same page. How can I remove the old URL? Besides doing a 301 redirect...

Comment: Note to everyone, there are some issues with overwriting the default URL for custom post types and taxonomies. For example, when you click the view category or post type in the admin panel, wordpress only knows the default URL. So if you do this re-write, we also needs to figure out how to tell Wordpress what the new URL is. And also tell SEO by Yoast and the site's sitemap.

Comment: You should add a filter for permalinks to be changed, like this:
    function custom_inventory_link( $url, $post ) {
        if ( 'inventory' === get_post_type( $post ) ) {
            $term = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'inventory_category' )[0];
            return get_term_link( $term ) . $post->name . '/';
        }
        return $url;
    }
    add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_inventory_link', 10, 2 );

Comment: And for the category:
    function custom_inventory_category_link( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {
        if ( 'inventory_category' === $taxonomy ) {
            return str_replace( 'inventory-category', 'inventory', $url );
        }
        return $url;
    }
    add_filter( 'term_link', 'custom_inventory_category_link', 10, 2 );