# Multiple custom post types with single taxonomy URL rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, url-routing

I've created 2 custom post types (let's call them "`cpt-1`" and "`cpt-2`").

These two CPTs share the same custom taxonomy (called "`category`").

I've done this with the ACF plugin.

**Here's the default URL structure:**

- Single post (cpt 1): `example.com/cpt-1/post-name`
- Single post (cpt 2): `example.com/cpt-2/post-name`
- Taxonomy archive: `example.com/category/category-name/subcategory-name`

**Here's what I need:**

- Single post (cpt 1): `example.com/cpt-1/category-name/post-name`
- Single post (cpt 2): `example.com/cpt-2/category-name/post-name`

This should also work if a single post is associated with a sub-category, for example, `example.com/cpt-1/category-name/subcategory-name/post-name`

- Taxonomy archive (showing cpt 1 posts only): `example.com/cpt-1/category-name/`
- Taxonomy archive (showing cpt 2 posts only) : `example.com/cpt-2/category-name/`

This should also work for sub-categories, for example `example.com/cpt-1/category-name/subcategory-name`

Is it possible to do this?

I've already consulted dozens of topics and articles. The simplest and most concise solution seems to be this: [Wordpress URL Rewrite to sync custom taxonomy and post type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890131/wordpress-url-rewrite-to-sync-custom-taxonomy-and-post-type)

I also find a code that manage hierachical taxonomy (category and subcategories) : https://gist.githubusercontent.com/igorbenic/3ba41de1db69bf028651e98b4615cfee/raw/c38bc462bbcfb21ebd1784ede59c5841767f5eb3/request2.php

From what I understand, a custom rewrite rule must be used to restructure URLs, and a `post_type_link` filter to display new URLs, but I don't have a good enough level of coding to adapt it to my case.

Here are the features I'm having trouble finding:

- Taxonomy hierarchy management in the URL (`example.com/cpt/category/subcategory/subsubcategory/post-name`)
- Use the same taxonomy archive for 2 different custom posts (`example.com/cpt-1/category` AND `example.com/cpt-2/category`). Besides, I don't even know if it's possible to separate the taxonomy archive according to the CPT.

If it's too complex, I'm tempted not to use taxonomy, and to create a page hierarchy for each CPT to have the URL structure I want easily (for example, inside a custom post type, create a "category-name" single post as parent page, and a "post-name" child single post).
What do you think about it?

Thanks in advance :)